# Maximizing the value of an implicit function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have $R$ as an implicit function of $N, K$ as defined in the following equation:

$$\left(1+K\frac{N}{12}\right)=\frac{R}{1+(1+R)^{-N}}$$

*For those interested, this equation came about as a result of my answer to the following question: [Most efficient method for converting flat rate interest to APR.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316788/most-efficient-method-for-converting-flat-rate-interest-to-apr/316812#316812)*

I would like to find, for fixed $K$, what value of $N$ maximizes $R$.

Unfortunately, implicit partial differentiation yields something quite ugly, as such:

$$\frac{\delta R}{\delta N}\left(\frac{RN}{1+R}-(1+R)^{N}-1)\right)=-R\ln{(1+R)}-\frac{K}{12}\left(1+(1+R)^{-N})^{2}\right)(1+R)^N$$

Is there any method to find the maximum value of $R$ using this approach, or is it the wrong one?

Comment: Just use a numerical root-finding algorithm on the derivative. Use a symbolic algebra package to get the derivative (if you want to use Newton's method), it will get worse ;-)

Comment: okay, I'm just slightly curious as to why $R$ is not maximized as $N$ is, because the financial intuition seems to suggest that it should be. Will look at a numerical root-finding algorithm then!

Comment: A simple one is the [secant method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), almost as fast (in terms of steps) than [Newton's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), but as it doesn't require messy derivatives it could turn out faster in practice. Or just look for numerical methods for finding maxima/minima.